# Dependency injection of IAuthSession resolves empty session

Tags: servicestack

I am successfully using ServiceStack's credentials authentication along with a custom AuthUserSession.  What I can't work out is how to use this in classes that have had dependencies injected via Funq.

I have several "Business" Classes which rely on Funq to inject the DAL dependency into them, this works perfectly.

However, within the DAL I obviously want to mark database fields such as "CreatedBy" and "ModifiedBy" with the currently logged in user id.  So, I create a constructor parameter in the DAL to receive the AuthUserSession.

Within Global.asax, the following lines are in place:

```
                //authentication
            Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new MyAuthUserSession(), 
                new IAuthProvider[] { new MyCredentialsAuthProvider() }));
```

No matter how I register MyAuthUserSession with funq, it resolves to an instance with no Session information in it.

```
container.Register<IAuthSession>(new MyAuthUserSession());
```

or

```
container.Register(new MyAuthUserSession());
```

In a nutshell; What is the best way of getting "Current User ID" into a class via constructor injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserSessions are not dependencies that are resolved from an IOC and as such should never be registered in an IOC which would be meaningless and cause confusion on how they actually work.

They are models that are hydrated from a Cache at runtime using the client's Cookies that are passed in with each HTTP Request. The [Session wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions) has more information about how Sessions work in ServiceStack.

Custom Typed User Sessions can be resolved in ServiceStack using the `base.SessionAs<T>` method, e.g:

```
public class MyService : Service
{
    public MyDependencyThatUsesUserSession MyDep { get; set; }

    public object Any(Request request)
    {
        MyAuthUserSession mySession = base.SessionAs<MyAuthUserSession>();
        return MyDep.Execute(mySession, request.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, makes total sense.